# "Cannot be cast to" Exception with Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I'm making an app where you enter information with buttons on one fragment then it sends the info back the the activity and replaces the fragment with another one that will display the information retrieved from the first fragment. However, I get an error: "com.example.cribbage2.CardKeyboardFrag cannot be cast to com.example.cribbage2.PCResultsFrag" and I don't know why.

Here is the activity's relevant code:

```
package com.example.cribbage2;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class PointCalculator extends FragmentActivity implements CardKeyboardFrag.InfoTransfer {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_point_calculator);

    //set cardKeyboardFrag
    CardKeyboardFrag cardFrag = new CardKeyboardFrag();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, cardFrag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

    //tell fragment how many cards you are requesting
}

public void cardNumSet(int cardNumMin, int cardNumMax){
    CardKeyboardFrag cardKeyboardFrag = (CardKeyboardFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    cardKeyboardFrag.cardNumGet(cardNumMin, cardNumMax);
}

public void displayResults(int[] resultsIntArray){

    //parse intArray into String
    String[] resultsStringArray = new String[4];
    int loop = 0;
    for (int num: resultsIntArray){
        resultsStringArray[loop] = Integer.toString(num);
        loop++;
    }

    //transfer to new fragment
    PCResultsFrag resultsFrag = new PCResultsFrag();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, resultsFrag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();


    //this is the line where the error occurs 
    PCResultsFrag pcResultsFrag = (PCResultsFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    pcResultsFrag.getResultsArray(resultsStringArray);
}
```

Comment: Well, `R.id.fragment_container` returns you a `CardKeyboardFrag`, as you already did in a prior line `CardKeyboardFrag cardKeyboardFrag = (CardKeyboardFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);`. But here you're trying to cast it to a `PCResultsFrag`, which is not compatible.

Comment: So what's the solution? How do I get the PCResultsFrag into the container? Or remove CardKeyboardFrag from the container?

Comment: @QBrute ^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the transaction like this:

```
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, resultsFrag , "resultsFrag");
```

And then get the object of the fragment like this:

```
 Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("resultsFrag");

 currentFragment.getResultsArray(resultsStringArray);
```

Comment: But I can't use `.getResultsArray` because `currentFragment` is an object of Fragment and not `PCResultsFrag`

Comment: whenever I try what you said, `.getResultsArray` turns red

Comment: Well I changed it and it works but now it says the object reference is null

Answer (score -1):

The resource id you're referencing in findFragmentById is for the Fragment Container View, not the Fragment in question.

```
PCResultsFrag pcResultsFrag = (PCResultsFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(**R.id.fragment_container**);
```

and

```
CardKeyboardFrag cardKeyboardFrag = (CardKeyboardFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(**R.id.fragment_container**);
```

Comment: Yes, is that not what I'm supposed to be doing?

Comment: Do you have an instance of each of these fragments declared in your manifest? If so, use the is attribute declared there. If the are shallowly created, then you're going to need a different way to retrieve the fragment from the fragment manager